# My pthread is not schedualing. In C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a program that takes the argument then dynamically allocating space for multiple `pthread_t`(array of pthread), then `pthread_create()` to load function.
The problem is that my first thread just doesn't stop running. My second thread will not even create before my first thread finish the whole process. How do I solve this problem?
Here is a simple code to demonstrate my problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t *ptr;
int num;

void* func(int id)
{
    while(1)
        printf("%d\n", id);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    num = atoi(argv[1]); //assuming arguments are always valid

    ptr = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*num);

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
        pthread_create(&ptr[i], NULL, func(i), NULL);

    //free allocated space

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that `0` is always printed, I never see `1`.
My guess is that ptr[1] never get the chance to initialize itself, so the thread doesn't exists. So it will not get it's cpu share.
Isn't the program itself has 1 main thread. After some process time, cpu should switch back to the main thread then pthread_create the second thread.It never happens. I'm just wondering why.

I'm a newbie in C, and this is my first time doing pthread. So please give advice that suits my level. Thank you.

Thanks to all the great advices, I have changed my code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int num;
pthread_t *ptr;

void* func(void* id)
{
  int *c;
  c = (int*)id;
  while(1)
    if(c)
      printf("%d\n", *c);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;

  num = atoi(argv[1]);

  ptr = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*num);
  for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    pthread_create(&ptr[i], NULL, func, (void*)&i);

  for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    pthread_join(ptr[i], NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

However, I still only see `0`. I created the thread now right?

Comment: what is `func(i)` in `pthread_create(&ptr[i], NULL, func(i), NULL);`

Comment: It is just pass the pthread to function func(), use i as argument for id?

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) of `pthread_create`.

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

> The pthread_create() function starts a new thread in the calling process.The new thread starts execution by invoking start_routine(). arg is passed as the sole argument of start_routine().

The correct way to supply arguments to the thread function is to use the `void *args` [which is `NULL` in your case].

You can do something like

```
void* func(void * id)
{
     int c;
     if (id)
     c = (int)*id;
    while(1)
        printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

and

```
 pthread_create(&ptr[i], NULL, func, (void *)&i);
```

---

EDIT:

As stated by David, to make sure the `main()` keeps on running as long as the thread functions are not terminted, you might consider to add the following

```
pthread_join(ptr[i], NULL)
```

---

The thread execution order is entirely dependent how scheduler runs individual threads and hence the order of operations is not guranted [includes the increment of `i` as a part of `main()`]. Try something like

Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void* func(void* id)
{
        int *c;
        c = (int*)id;
        // while(1)    //removing infinite loop for ease of o/p
        if(c)
                printf("%d\n", *c);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i = 0;
        int *index = NULL;
        int num;
        pthread_t *ptr;
        if (argv[1])
                num = atoi(argv[1]);

        index = calloc (num, sizeof (int));
        for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
                index[i] = i;
        }

        ptr = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*num);
        for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
                pthread_create(&ptr[i], NULL, func, (void*)&index[i]);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
                pthread_join(ptr[i], NULL);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean I create it as: pthread_create(&ptr[i], NULL, &func(), &i)?

Comment: The define of `void* func(int id)` is not right, it should be `void* func(void* id)`.

Comment: @BlackMamba was updating my answer to include the same. :-)

Comment: Also, when `main` returns, that terminates your process, which is not what you want.

Comment: The compiler says: warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer [enabled by default] c = (int)*id;

Comment: That's wierd. If I replace the while loop with for loop. All threads will be created, and they all will print certain amount of numbers, then after everything is done, the process will terminate. I'm only creating thread right? not forking process.

Comment: @user3685525 well, there are differences between process and threads. `mian()` will finish its execution and exit, when the threads will be in exection, as per the current code.

Comment: @user3685525 ok, as for the warning, you can change existing thread function code to `int *c; c = (int *)id; while(1) if (c) printf("%d\n", *c);`

Comment: I just modified the code according to your advice. I believe I'm creating threads now. However, I still only see 0s.

Comment: @user3685525: No, just `func`. If you write `func()` then what's passed to `pthread_create` is the return value of a single execution of `func`. You don't want *that* to be called as thread func. You want `func` to be called. Just that.

Answer (score 2):

Just to point out whats actually happening with your code - to work as intended, [`pthread_create()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create) needs a *pointer* to the function that should run in a new thread.

What you are doing is:

```
pthread_create(&ptr[i], NULL, func(i), NULL);
```

Instead of passing `func` as a pointer, you call the function directly. Since the arguments to `pthread_create()` need to be evaluated before `pthread_create()` can be called, `func()` is thus run - but in your main thread, before even getting around to starting a new thread.  And since `func()` consists of an infinite loop, you'll never get around to seeing anything but the output of `func(0)`.

To call `pthread_create()` correctly, use a function pointer to it, which you can very easily get by just leaving out the `()` part (as pointed out by some of the other answers, you can pass your `i` argument to `func()` in the fourth argument to `pthread_create()`). That is:

```
pthread_create(&ptr[i], NULL, func, (void*)i);
```

Also, other things to note (as pointed out by the other answers), you should change `func()` to take a `void*` argument, and make sure that your main thread keeps running after spawning the threads - either by entering an infinite loop of sorts, or by calling [`pthread_join()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join) to wait for the spawned threads to terminate

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
pthread_create(&ptr[i], NULL, func, (void*)&i)
```

The thread creation order is unpredictable. So thread-one may get initialized with thread-two's argument. Its not safe to use same variables while creating multiple threads in a loop.

As indicated in the above answer, use separate variables for all threads.

```
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
            index[i] = i;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
            pthread_create(&ptr[i], NULL, func, (void*)&index[i]);
    }
```